# あれが for "that must be it"?

Tags: phrases, particle-が

I'm watching an anime where the protagonist says, according to the subtitles, "that must be it!" But what it sounds like he's saying "あれが" instead of "あれだ". I know I may be hearing incorrectly, but is it possible for "あれが" to be said in a way that would translate to "That must be it"?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a very brief sound clip with us?  (I ask because you feel you may have misheard it.)

Comment: Please note that subtitles are almost never direct translations as they are designed to make sense to native speakers of another language. Several sentences may be translated entirely differently to get the same point across. This is especially true with some points where the two languages don't necessarily have good equivalents, and a direct translation would just cause confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way for it to be `あれが` and make sense is if it's in response to some question.  Although that would be emphasizing the ***that*** in "That must be it".

> - 何が一番偉いものなんだ？　→　What's the best/greatest one (thing)?
> - あれが！　→　That one (is)! / That must be it!

If you're sure the pronunciation isn't `だ`, there's a slight possibility they could be saying `あれや！` where `や` is the Kansai-ben equivalent of `だ` and slightly mistakable for `が` if said fast enough.

Comment: I feel like with あれが there's some verb that's being omitted for brevity. Do you know what it is? I'm thinking あれが（探しているのです）, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Ataraxia:  With my example, they're omitting the `一番偉いもの((なん)だ)` since it doesn't need to be repeated.  In general, it depends on what's being discussed.

Comment: I think "あれが" goes better as a response to "どれが" rather than "何が".